# arm_neon.h:9193:17: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'uint32_t' when build rust docker image in mac book M1 chip

Tags: docker, rust, actix-web

When I tried to build a simple [actix-web](https://actix.rs/) hello world rust application in mac book pro with M1 pro chip, shows error like this:

```
#10 26.01   cargo:warning=15826 | vld1_dup_s8 (const int8_t* __a)
#10 26.01   cargo:warning=      |                          ^
#10 26.01   cargo:warning=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/include/arm_neon.h:9209:1: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'vaddlv_s32'
#10 26.01   cargo:warning= 9209 | vaddlv_s32 (int32x2_t __a)
#10 26.01   cargo:warning=      | ^~~~~~~~~~
#10 26.01   cargo:warning=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/include/arm_neon.h:9216:1: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'vaddlv_u32'
#10 26.01   cargo:warning= 9216 | vaddlv_u32 (uint32x2_t __a)
#10 26.01   cargo:warning=      | ^~~~~~~~~~
#10 26.01   cargo:warning=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/include/arm_neon.h:15833:28: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
#10 26.01   cargo:warning=15833 | vld1_dup_s16 (const int16_t* __a)
#10 26.01   cargo:warning=      |                            ^
#10 26.01   cargo:warning=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/include/arm_neon.h: In function 'vtbl1_s8':
#10 26.01   cargo:warning=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/include/arm_neon.h:15840:28: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
```

this is the rust `main.rs`:

```
use actix_web::{get, post, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};

#[get("/")]
async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}

#[post("/echo")]
async fn echo(req_body: String) -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body(req_body)
}

async fn manual_hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hey there!")
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .service(hello)
            .service(echo)
            .route("/hey", web::get().to(manual_hello))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

this is the `cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "alt-server"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
```

and this is the `dockerfile`:

```
# build stage
FROM rust:1.69.0-alpine3.17 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN rustup default stable
RUN cargo build --release
# RUN cargo build
FROM rust:1.69.0-alpine3.17
LABEL maintainer="jiang@gmail.com"
WORKDIR /app
ENV ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
# ENV ROCKET_PORT=11014
RUN apk update && apk add curl 
#
# only copy the execute file to minimal the image size
# do not copy the release folder
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/alt-server /app/
CMD ["./alt-server"]
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: Did you try with `rust:1.69-slim-bullseye` instead of `rust:1.69.0-alpine3.17`? The system libraries provided with alpine may not contain all what you need.

Comment: is it possible to use the alpine base image? @prog-fh

Comment: I don't know precisely the limitations, but I already encountered the situation where a trivial Rust program finds everything it needs in an alpine image, but a more elaborated one (with many dependencies) ends up with some missing resources. I had to switch to a debian-based image. (bullseye-silm is not so big)

Comment: I will try to switch to bullseye, using alpine will save some space, that's why I using this base image.

Comment: For the final image, once the code is compiled, you can also use [`gcr.io/distroless/cc-debian11`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) which is supposed to be quite small too.